How to load and render a 2D tilemap from a JSON file in C using raylib?
I'm a beginner in programming and game development, and I'm trying to create a simple 2D game using C and the raylib library. I've designed a map in Tiled and exported it as a JSON file. Now, I'm struggling to figure out how to load this JSON file in my C code and render the tilemap on the screen using raylib.
I've searched for examples, but most of them are either in other languages or a bit too advanced for me to understand. Could someone please explain or provide a simple example of how to:
Load a JSON tilemap file in C.
Parse the JSON data to extract the tilemap information.
Render the tilemap using raylib.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please be aware that you should only post one question per post. Therefore let's focus on the loading of your data. Rendering is a totally different thing and you should post another question for it. What exactly is your problem? Is it loading a JSON file in general, or is it related to your 2D maze that you stored as JSON? Please be more specific. Please also edit your question to include a MCVE showing how your data structures look and how far you got. No need to include the raylib part. Additionally, please add sample json data.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
